# Linux with desktop enviroment using XRDP on Archlinux on WSL does not working

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

A newbie here.

Well I spent a couple days trying to make work xrdp for Archlinux on WSL. Actually WSL does not support Arch but can be installed using docker.

I have ubuntu on wsl too and I use xrdp there to use xfce and gnome as Desktop enviroment and everything works so well.

The first thing that I noticed on Arch: there is not `/etc/init.d` directory and I think is needed for xrdp, on many tutorials the command to enable and start services are on that folder. (https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-enable-wsl2-ubuntu-gui-and-use-rdp-to-remote , https://dev.to/darksmile92/linux-on-windows-wsl-with-desktop-environment-via-rdp-522g)

Xrdp package is downloaded and installed from AUR repositories, so maybe there is a way to make it work, don't know how.

Where the files (that should be on `/etc/init.d` for another distros) are?

How can I make it work?

I clearly think that I am missing a lot of info, so hope a lot you can help me while I'm learning.

Comment: I put XRDP on Ubuntu and XRDP on Kali. Standard (very standard) XRDP installs.  Are you sure WSL has the necessary underlying Linux libraries for XRDP?

Comment: @Jhon Well, I worked with XRDP before, as I said. I used succesfully with Ubuntu and Kali, using gnome and xfce. So I know that works on WSL. I think is a issue with the directories and files. Specificaly with /etc/init.d.

Comment: Arch has moved to systemd that doesn't use init.d. You might try to use instead FreeRDP as a server. See [link1](https://devicetests.com/ubuntu-remote-desktop-freerdp). I also don't know if this old [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481925/963426) is useful, but it's pretty detailed.

Comment: @harrymc I'm going to try that way. Then I'll tell here what happens. Thank you